# When I want to update my app at play store with bug fixes and no change in DB, Does existing database remains as is or not?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I want to update my app at play store with bug fixes. APP already uses Room DB. Do i need to migrate the DB. There is no change in the DB. There are only UI changes. Does new version effect the people DB, who are already using it. Can someone provide the details about this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No you don't need to, you should only upgrade the database version if something changes, otherwise it's not necessary

Answer (score 0):

> There is no change in the DB.

The database remains and you do not need to change the version of the database (as per the `@Database(`  .... `version=?)`).

You only need to change (increase) the database version if the schema has changed.

If you increase the version number and do not have a migration *(migration class to call)* to cover that version, then an **IllegalStateException** will occur unless you have **.fallbackToDestructiveMigration()** which WILL delete and recreate the database (effectively empty the database with the ne schema).

- You can also use **fallbackToDestructiveMigrationFrom()**

**It is the version number that determines if a database migration is required**. However, if a change is made and if any of the entities mismatch the database when the .build method is run then an exception will result.

- If you change an Entity (the schema) and do not increase the version number you will get an **IllegalStateException** with the message starting with **Room cannot verify the data integrity.** This is because the hash stored in the room_master_table has changed.
- If you changed the database schema outside of room then you'd get an exception indicating that the expected schema (the database according to the Entities) does not match the schema found (the database according to the actual database).

**In your situation I'd suggest not changing the version number.**

You may wish to have a look at:-

- [Migrating Room Databases](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions)
- [@Database](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/room/Database)
- [fallbackToDestructiveMigration](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/room/RoomDatabase.Builder#fallbacktodestructivemigration)
- [fallbackToDestructiveMigrationFrom](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/room/RoomDatabase.Builder#fallbacktodestructivemigrationfrom)